# Printing words from text file

Tags: java, file, match

I have this program right now that runs a txt file and prints the lines from the file that start with A or T. Now I am tying to make it so that it will just print the words that end with an , or ;  Anyone think they could help me?

Here is my program rn

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("amazing.txt")); 
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();

        while (sf.hasNextLine()) {
            String current = sf.nextLine(); 
            if (current.startsWith("T") || current.startsWith("A")) {
                System.out.println(current);
            }
        }
        sf.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use **try-with-resources** to ensure that your scanner is always closed. Right now, `sf.close()` is not executed if you trigger an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String#endsWith` ?

```
while (sf.hasNextLine()) {
    String current = sf.nextLine(); 
    if (current.endsWith(",") || current.endsWith(";"))
        System.out.println(current);
}
```

A slightly more sophisticated solution might be to use regex matching to do this check:

```
while (sf.hasNextLine()) {
    String current = sf.nextLine(); 
    if (current.matches(".*[,;]\\s*"))
        System.out.println(current);
}
```

This would check that each line ends in comma or semicolon, possibly with some whitespace afterward.

Answer (score 1):

*@TimBiegeleisen* already provided a great answer.

For completeness, let me also provide a **stream-based** solution that uses **NIO** (Javas newer, modern File API) which is using his check:

```
Files.lines(Path.of("amazing.txt"))
    .filter(line -> line.matches(".*[,;]\\s*"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The code requires at least Java 11 because of `Path.of`. Or Java 8 if you use `Paths.get("amazing.txt")` instead.

---

In case you intended to add those lines to `text` instead of printing them, you can easily modify the code:

```
Files.lines(Path.of("amazing.txt"))
    .filter(line -> line.matches(".*[,;]\\s*"))
    .forEach(text::add);
```

Or let the stream create the list itself, then you do not have to do it:

```
List<String> text = Files.lines(Path.of("amazing.txt"))
    .filter(line -> line.matches(".*[,;]\\s*"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you, I am understanding this much more now.